# Saving additional context with a view

Tags: android

I have `GridView` which shows a list of thumbnails. After clicking on one of them I'd like to navigate to another activity with detailed view of a corresponding "thing".

How should I store some additional data/identifiers such that on click I can pass it to the detailed activity? By default I only get position and id. I'd like to somehow store my custom identifier which I use to query external services for details.

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                            int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MovieDetails.class);
        intent.putExtra(MY_ID, <some_extra_ID>);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

**EDIT:**

For example, I have a dynamic list of dishes with only photos of that dish (using GridView). When user clicks on one of them I want to show a detailed view with a recipe and comments.

For that I need to pass name of that dish to load information in the detailed view.

Comment: Please elaborate, What you want to pass?

Comment: Does it mean you want to send data that binding to selected view to another activity?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is as good as a click listener can get as it passes the `view`, `position` and `id`. However you can improve the data you get by defining a unique item **id** inside your **adapter**.

If you are using an `ArrayAdapter` or `SimpleAdapter` the **id** is usually the same as **position** but for a `CursorAdapter` or `SimpleCursorAdapter` the **id** returns the **row id** of the **table**.

Now you can **extend** you **adapter** and return the desired **id** inside the `getItemId` method:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyItem>{

        ...
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return myItems.get(position).myUniqueId;
        }
}
```